# Special characters getting converted into ascii

Tags: java, url

I need to pass a string as it is but at the back end the special characters are getting converted.How to avoid this? Please find below my code how I am doing it.

```
My String "1nIH6iLxXVYBj0J\/JhDlQmSm9aAtjz7ynZpaJ4bxcko="
At the backen "1nIH6iLxXVYBj0J%5C%2FJhDlQmSm9aAtjz7ynZpaJ4bxcko%3D"

Part of my code::
oauthMessage = computeOAuthRequest("POST", appId, appSecret,URLEncoder.encode(authToken,"UTF-8"), url);
```

Comment: You're calling `URLEncoder.encode`, which is encoding the values as requested... you just need to decode them on the backend...

Comment: It looks like a Base64 URL-non-safe token. If should be the case, you could instead [Base64 URL-safe encode/decode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#URL_applications), so that you don't need to URL encode.

Comment: At backend I cannot do anything. so I need to pass directly that string without using URLEncoder?

Comment: Try "Cp1252" too. This gives other %-escaping. With a bit of luck the backend is set to ISO-8859-1 and recognizes that.